# How to print un packed 3 dimension arry using foreach in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

```
module array1;

int md[1:2][1:4][1:3];
int cnt;

initial
begin
    foreach(md[i][j][k])
    begin
         md[i][j][k]=cnt;
         cnt++;
    end       

    foreach(md[i])
    begin
           $display("%d :::::",i);
           foreach(md[,j]);
           begin
               $write("%d : ",j);
               foreach(md[,k]);
                    $write("%d ",md[i][j][k]);
           end
    end      

endmodule
```

Not getting expected output by above program.

Comment: what is your expected output, describe your problem.

Comment: No need for nested `foreach` loops. For multi-dimensional array, use `foreach(md[i,j,k])` (Note syntax here). Please be elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below a code with its output.

```
module array1;

  int md[1:2][1:4][1:3]; int cnt;

  initial
    begin
      foreach(md[i])
        begin
          $display("\nlayer ",i);
          foreach(md[,j])
            begin
              foreach(md[,,k])
                begin
                  md[i][j][k]=cnt; 
                  $write(md[i][j][k]);          
                  cnt++;
                end  
              $display();
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
layer           1
          0          1          2 
          3          4          5 
          6          7          8 
          9         10         11 

layer           2
         12         13         14 
         15         16         17 
         18         19         20 
         21         22         23
```

Comment: I want it to print like matrix/block. it prints [2][4][4] instead of [2][4][3].

Comment: @Bhoo_Raj, I have edited a code. Please check the answer. I think this is what you are expecting.